# NullPointerException while trying to calculate text width in custom component

Tags: android, custom-controls

I have a custom control that extends `RelativeLayout`. Inside i have a `ImageButton` and a `TextView`. This is part of the code:

```
    public CustomImageButton(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_image_button, this);
            this.setClickable(false);
            setupViewItems();
        }

        public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_image_button, this);
            this.setClickable(false);
            TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomImageButton);
            setAttributes(attributes);
            setupViewItems();
            attributes.recycle();
        }
    private void setupViewItems() {
            final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


            final String text = this.text;
            final int paddingTopPercentage = this.textTopPadding;
            final int textAlignment = this.textAlignment;

            textView.setText(text);
            textView.setTextSize(this.textSize);
            textView.setTextColor(this.textColor);

            ViewTreeObserver vto = imageButton.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    int imageHeight = imageButton.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int imageWidth = imageButton.getMeasuredWidth();

                    boolean isTextInCorrectSize = true;
                    int textWidth = 0;
                    do {

                        if (!isTextInCorrectSize)
                            textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize() - 1f);

                        Rect bounds = new Rect();
                        Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
// BUG HERE - I GET A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION WHEN RUNNING getTextBounds function
                        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
                        //int textHeight = bounds.height();
                        textWidth = bounds.width();
                        isTextInCorrectSize = (imageWidth - textWidth) > 0; 

                    }while(!isTextInCorrectSize);

                    //DOING SOME STUFF HERE
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

I don't know if its relevant but this control, in some parts of the app, is added directly in the layout xml and sometimes I need to programmatically add the component (hence the 2 different constructors). If the custom component is added via the layout xml - then i don't have any problems BUT when i add the custom component via code i get a NullPointerException when executing the getTextBounds function (see code above). When I debug and evaluate all the parameters and the textView that calls the function - nothing is null. Any ideas on why and how i can overcome this?
Thanks
**EDIT:** This is the stack trace:

```
'java.lang.NullPointerException' with message 'null'. Stack trace:
        com.company.product.ui.views.CustomImageButton$1.onPreDraw(CustomImageButton.java:155)
        android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:571)
        android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1259)
        android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    *****************
    ****** GMT Time: 17 Feb 2013 13:09:36 GMT
    ****** Application name: AppName
    ****** User agent: (Android 2.3.3)
    ******************************
    ****** Exception type: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ****** Exception message: null
    ****** Trace trace:
        com.company.product.ui.views.CustomImageButton$1.onPreDraw(CustomImageButton.java:155)
        android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:571)
        android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1259)
        android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add the traceback please?

Comment: Hello @Fred - Question was edited and now contains stack trace. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact you are retrieving the size (bounds) of the TextView in the constructor of your class (you call `setupViewItems()`) which you cannot do because Android has not yet drawn it and hence determined the size
.
Instead you must size/retrieve the size of your View items by overriding  [View.onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method. Android always calls this method once it has sized a View even for the very first time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - if what you say is correct, please explain why this problem occurs only when i add the custom component programmatically but not when i add it via the layout xml?

Comment: That I cannot answer except suggest Android lays out Views differently when from XML as opposed to in code. One thing is for sure though, onSizechanged() WILL be called if you use XML or code. I had similar problems in the past and the way I resolved it was to wait for onSizeChanged() to be called before I could be sure the sizes of my Views were available.